# PandasDataframe to_datetime error

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have got the following indices on a dataframe:

```
data extracted Index(['2014-06-30 00:00:00.0', '2014-07-07 00:00:00.0',
       '2014-08-11 00:00:00.0', '2014-08-18 00:00:00.0',
       '2014-08-25 00:00:00.0', '2014-09-08 00:00:00.0',
       '2014-09-22 00:00:00.0', '2014-09-29 00:00:00.0',
       '2014-10-06 00:00:00.0', '2014-10-27 00:00:00.0',
       '2014-11-24 00:00:00.0', '2014-12-15 00:00:00.0',
       '2014-12-29 00:00:00.0', '2015-01-05 00:00:00.0',
       '2015-01-19 00:00:00.0', '2015-01-26 00:00:00.0',
       '2015-02-02 00:00:00.0', '2015-02-16 00:00:00.0',
       '2015-02-23 00:00:00.0', '2015-04-13 00:00:00.0',
       '2015-04-20 00:00:00.0', '2015-05-04 00:00:00.0',
       '2015-05-25 00:00:00.0', '2015-06-01 00:00:00.0',
       '2015-06-15 00:00:00.0', '2015-06-22 00:00:00.0',
       '2015-06-29 00:00:00.0', '2015-07-13 00:00:00.0',
       '2015-07-20 00:00:00.0', '2015-08-17 00:00:00.0',
       '2015-08-24 00:00:00.0', '2015-08-31 00:00:00.0',
       '2015-09-07 00:00:00.0', '2015-10-05 00:00:00.0',
       '2015-10-12 00:00:00.0', '2015-10-19 00:00:00.0',
       '2015-11-09 00:00:00.0', '2015-11-16 00:00:00.0',
       '2015-11-30 00:00:00.0', '2016-01-18 00:00:00.0',
       '2016-02-01 00:00:00.0', '2016-02-15 00:00:00.0',
       '2016-02-29 00:00:00.0', '2016-03-14 00:00:00.0',
       '2016-04-04 00:00:00.0', '2016-04-11 00:00:00.0',
       '2016-04-25 00:00:00.0', '2016-05-16 00:00:00.0',
       '2016-05-30 00:00:00.0', '2016-06-20 00:00:00.0',
       '2016-06-27 00:00:00.0', '2016-07-18 00:00:00.0',
       '2016-08-01 00:00:00.0', '2016-08-15 00:00:00.0',
       '2016-08-22 00:00:00.0', '2016-09-12 00:00:00.0',
       '2016-10-03 00:00:00.0', '2016-11-07 00:00:00.0',
       '2016-11-14 00:00:00.0', '2016-11-21 00:00:00.0',
       '2016-12-05 00:00:00.0', '2016-12-19 00:00:00.0', 'DATE'],
      dtype='object', name='DATE')
```

I want to do a weekly resampling on monday on this dataframe indices, so i need to convert them to a datetime index:

```
data = pd.read_csv('statistic.csv', 
parse_dates=True, index_col=['DATE'], low_memory=False)
data[['QUANTITY']] = data[['QUANTITY']].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
data_extracted = data.groupby(['DATE','ARTICLENO']) 
['QUANTITY'].sum().unstack()
data_extracted = data_extracted.fillna(value=np.nan)
data_extracted.index = pd.to_datetime(data_extracted.index)
```

When i try to convert the index like above, i get an error:

```
ValueError: Unknown string format
```

I think it is the last entry ('DATE'). How can i remove this?
`data_extracted.index[:-1]`?
How to convert to a weekly series? I know the `.resample('W-MON')` but read about some bugs and unexpected behaviour. Additionally, my data is not in regular distance, there is data every monday but not every seven days.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
data_extracted.index = pd.to_datetime(data_extracted.index.str[:-2], errors='coerce')
```

Comment: Is there a need to remove the last two parts of the string? I do not think so since The data is in the correct format before the period

Comment: Yes, because they are part of the index